# How to dismiss the Authentication View Controller in mobile SDK 7.0?

Tags: salesforce-ios-sdk

With SDK 7.0 version of the mobile sdk we are looking for a way to dismiss the auth view controller. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following. The SDK uses multiple windows to display auth related prompts. If at any point you need to dismiss it using the SFSDKWindowManager.

```
    SFSDKWindowManager.shared().authWindow.dismissWindow(animated: false) {
        // called when dismiss is complete. Make the  application window 
       active.
      }
```